# Show that the systems $\{1,t^2,t^4,\dots\}$ and $\{1,t,t^3,\dots\}$ are complete on $L^2[a,b]$ if $0\notin[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Show that the systems $\{1,t^2,t^4,\dots\}$ and $\{1,t,t^3,\dots\}$ are complete on $L^2[a,b]$ if $0\notin[a,b]$

A system of vectors $\{v_i\}$ is complete on a topological linear space $L$ if the closure of its generating space is the whole linear space $\left(\overline{\operatorname{span}\{v_i\}}=L\right)$.

I know that the polynomials are dense in the continuous function and any function on $L^2[a,b]$ can be approached with continuous functions, so any function on $L^2[a,b]$ can be approached with polynomials, but if I have just pair or odd (and the $1$) polynomials, how can I approached $f$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume $0 \le a < b$. Define $\Phi : L^2 [a,b] \to L^2[-b,b]$ by

$$\Phi f(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if } x \in [a,b] \\ 0 &\text{if } x \in [-a,a] \\ f(-x)  & \text{if } x \in [-b,-a] \end{cases}$$

The image of $\Phi$ lies in the space of even functions $L_E$ in $L^2[-b,b]$. Note that $\{t, t^3, t^5, \cdots\}$ is orthogonal to $L_E$ and so $\{1, t^2, t^4, \cdots \}$ forms a complete set in $L_E$. Restricting to $[a,b]$ and note that $\Phi$ is an embedding so that $\|\Phi f\|_2 = 2 \|f\|_2$, 
$$\{1, t^2, t^4, \cdots \}$$
forms a complete set in $L^2[a,b]$.

Similarly by extending $f$ to an odd functions in $[-b, b]$, one can show that 
$$\{t, t^3, t^5, \cdots \}$$
forms a complete set in $L^2[a,b]$.